# Downloading PDF - can't open it

Tags: php, pdf, mime

I let my users download a PDF-file using this code:

The `$db->Record['file']` contains the relative path to the document.

The access a dummy page that loads the pdf, so they do not actually see the "text.pdf" in the url. I changed the headers of the file to achieve this:

```
$downloadfile = '/data/srv/www/vhosts/htdocs'.$db->Record['file'];
$filename = basename($downloadfile);        
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');        
readfile($downloadfile);
```

The download works without any problems, but when I try to open it, the following error ocurrs:

```
The PDF file could not be openend, the type is not supported or the file
was damaged.
```

How can I fix this?

Not: When I download the file directly, meaning to access is via `http://.../text.pdf` and open it, everything works fine.

Comment: What does the downloaded file actually contain?

Comment: I'll bet a beer there are PHP error messages in the file.

Comment: I'll bet a case of beer that those PHP errors result from the file htdocstext.pdf not existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from the comments) I'll bet a beer there are PHP error messages in the file.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the browser is unable to tell the length of the expected read from the file. From the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), try adding the file size in the header:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss a `/` after `htdocs` in the first line?